# What is this code means?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I have just employed in a company, this company have a web site, i see some code like this:

```
 public TicketReader()
    {
        HttpContext currentReq = HttpContext.Current;

        try
        {

            Ticket = ((FormsIdentity)currentReq.User.Identity).Ticket;
        }
        catch
        {

            Ticket = null;
        }
    }
```

what are these codes mean?

Comment: Without context, no one else can know what it actually means. I suggest you go to your manager or a team member, i.e., someone actually familiar with the code you're working on, for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TicketReader is a method that saves the information involving the visitor's individual HTTP request in a variable called currentReq. That variable will be used to create a Ticket-object. If it fails the Ticket-object is set to be nothing, which will probably be checked later on.

[More information on HttpContext class by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is it looks at the current http request and sets a ticket to the user, if that throws an error it sets the ticket to null(instead of the error type the command probably returns)

I would learn about httprequests if I were you and it will start making sense

what it basically does it break hierarchy intentionally(useful yet dangerous if you don't understand what you are doing)